# multi-able check boxes with hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I'm a bit of a noob at jQuery so here goes...

I have 3 checkboxes, and i want to hide my  tag if one of the check boxes is checked, but i then want all the others to unhide if they are not checked and then at the same time if 2 check boxes are check i want to hid all assoiated with those checkboxes

i hope this make sense, and any help is much aprichated

Many thanks

```
<input type="checkbox" class="example" id="check1"><label>check1</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="example" id="check2"><label>check2</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="example" id="check3"><label>check3</label>

<a class="check1" href="">check1</a>
<a class="check2" href="">check2</a>
<a class="check3" href="">check3</a>

<a class="check1" href="">check1</a>
<a class="check2" href="">check2</a>
<a class="check3" href="">check3</a>

<a class="check1" href="">check1</a>
<a class="check2" href="">check2</a>
<a class="check3" href="">check3</a>



    .hide {
      display: none;
    }



    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      $('#check1').change(function() {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
          $(".check1").addClass("hide");
        } else {
          $(".check1").removeClass("hide");
        }
      });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a few things before it works:

1. Make it generic for all the checkboxes. Bind the `.example` instead.
2. Get the ID dynamically from the clicked checkbox.
3. Encapsulate everything inside `$(document).ready()` function.
4. Encapsulate the `<input />` and label text inside the `<label>` tag!

I have modified the HTML to make it look better and semantic.

**Working Snippet:**

```js
$(function () {
  $('.example').change(function() {
    theID = this.id;
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $("." + theID).addClass("hide");
    } else {
      $("." + theID).removeClass("hide");
    }
  });

  // Check while loading.
  $(".example").each(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked"))
      $("." + this.id).addClass("hide");
  });
  
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="example" id="check1">check1</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="example" id="check2" checked>check2</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="example" id="check3">check3</label>
</div>

<div>
  <a class="check1" href="">check1</a>
  <a class="check2" href="">check2</a>
  <a class="check3" href="">check3</a>
</div>

<div>
  <a class="check1" href="">check1</a>
  <a class="check2" href="">check2</a>
  <a class="check3" href="">check3</a>
</div>

<div>
  <a class="check1" href="">check1</a>
  <a class="check2" href="">check2</a>
  <a class="check3" href="">check3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: hi this works well, but is it possible to make it if a a tag has check1 and check2 class to show if ether check box was selected?

Comment: Yes, use `if ($(elem).hasClass("check1")) // Do that`.

Comment: thanks sorry to be a pain can you add it to the snippet?

Comment: its not working quite right  <a class="check1 check2" href="">check1</a> if my a tag is like this, and both check 1 and check 2 are clicked then i take check 1 off it still removes the hide class..

Comment: Oh Okay! That's something else.

Comment: shoudl i re ask the question?

Comment: @DanielEdwards No Buddy. Not needed. I will update in my answer, I got what you wanna do. So, for multiple stuff, you need to check everytime the status and hide / show accordingly. So, I am in the office right now, give me an hour, I will update and send you a message! `:D`

Answer (score 1):

use toggle()

```
$('.example[type=checkbox]').change(function() {  
    $("."+this.id).toggle(!this.checked);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7v4qbxr5/1/)**

Comment: hi, is it possible to do i so that if one is checked it unhides all the other and unchecks the other check boxes?

Comment: Then you can use radio button in this case

Answer (score 0):

```
you can this jquery code :

$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {
            var chkId = $(this).attr("id");
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                $("." + chkId).addClass("hide");
            } else {
                $("." + chkId).removeClass("hide");
            }
        });
```